# How to Split String and get Number form it?

Tags: javascript

I have one string "I_am_125_developer_25" and want result 150 means 125+25 using javascript

```
var a = "I_am_125_developer_25";
```

I tried following solution

```
for(var i = 0; i<= a.length; i++)
{ 
    if(typeof a[i] == Number) 
    { 
        var c = a[i]; console.log(c); 
    } 
}
```

Here I need to add two numbers from string need to check whether it is number or not.

Comment: Are you definitely only splitting by `_`, or just grab any numbers? Also are decimals allowed?

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
"I_am_125_developer_25".match(/\d+/g).reduce( (a,b) => Number(a) + Number(b) )
```

Explanation

- `Match` numbers, get the array ["125", "25"]
- `Reduce` the array by adding the converted (to Number) array items (reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce))

**Edit**

If you also want to support the scenarios like `"I_am_1x5_developer_25"`, then make it

```
"I_am_1x5_developer_25".split(/_/).filter( s => !isNaN(s) ).reduce( (a,b) => Number(a) + Number(b) );
```

Explanation

- `split` by `_`
- `filter` out non-numeric values
- `Reduce` the array by adding the converted (to Number) array items

Comment: `var a = "I_am_1x5_developer_25"` => 31?

Comment: @Rhumborl Not sure if OP wanted to handle this scenario, but added the fix for the same anyways. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getSumFromString(str) {
  var total = 0;
  str.split('_').forEach(function(e){
    var num = parseInt(e);
    if(num) {
        total +=num;
    }
  });
  return total;
}

getSumFromString('I_am_125_developer_25');
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution

```
    var total = 0;
for(var i=0; i<=arr.length; i++){
    if(!isNaN(arr[i])) {
    total+=Number(arr[i]);
}
}
console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to split the string and make it an array, loop through it, verify which are numbers using `isNaN()` method and sum up the numbers:

```js
var a = "I_am_125_developer_25";
a = a.split('_');
var sum = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
  if(!isNaN(a[i])){
    sum += parseInt(a[i]);
  }
}
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer,  I did same. Thanks alot!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var string = "I_am_125_developer_25";
var regex = /(\d+)/g;
var numArray = string.match(regex);
var sum=0;
for (var i=0;i<numArray.length;i++){
  sum+=parseInt(numArray[i]);
}
console.log(sum);
```